# PHP similar methods across classes, but different member varaible scope?

Tags: php

I have two classes that are similar, but have different scope for member variables. I'll minimize it to

```
class LimitedADAData{
       private $member;
       public function mapMember($map){
           //use $this->member with $map      
       }
}
class ADAData{
       public $member;
       public function mapMember($map){
          //use $this->member with $map
       }
}
```

Traits, interfaces, and abstract classes must declare scope right? So what do you do when reused methods don't care what the scope of the variable is, but the rest of the class does?

For example, doing this...

```
interface DataMethods{
    public $member;
    public function mapMember($map);
 }
```

...would not fit LimitedADAData, which has a private $member

But leaving out the variable

```
interface DataMethods{
    public function mapMember($map);
 }
```

is bad because the mapMember function looks for a $member variable, so I am actually leaving out a dependency.

Comment: The internal implementation of methods is not part of the interface. The `mapMember` functions don't care whether the property is public or private, they'll work the same either way.

Comment: right, but the interface cares if the class implements the property as public or private, even if the function doesn't.

Comment: An interface only specifies the aspects of the class that are visible to users of the class, i.e. its public properties and methods. You can have additional properties besides the ones required by the interface. And the interface doesn't specify which methods use which properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php):

> All methods declared in an interface must be public; this is the nature of an interface.

It's not even possible to declare properties in interfaces, that's not their purpose.
If you do you'll get:

```
 Fatal error: Interfaces may not include member variables
```

I would recommend reading the top comment on the manual page linked above: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#107364

The interface doesn't care about the implementation of the method at all, it is just a contract specifying what the implementing classes should do with their public facing methods. Which public or private methods or properties are used by the class to fulfill the contract doesn't matter to the interface.

You are not leaving out a dependency by omitting the property in your interface, you are strengthening the abstraction.

Comment: Very well put. To bring it back to the specific example in the question: the `mapMember` implementation in a given class *might* look for a `$member` variable, but it might not: it might use a variable with a different name; or look it up in a database, or generate a random number. It just needs to meet the contract specified in the interface - which could include parameters (enforced or in doc block), return type (can be enforced in PHP 7, or in doc block if PHP 5), exceptions thrown (in doc block), and perhaps some unenforced description in the doc block of the *visible* effect.